# What is $2^{2^{23}} \pmod {100}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is $2^{2^{23}} \pmod {100}$?

I have found that $2^{12} \equiv -4 \pmod {100}$, and solved it but it, gets very tedious this way. Any other smart way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Clearly $2^{2^{23}}\equiv 0 \pmod 4$, so you only need to find $2^{2^{23}}$ modulo 25 and apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem. For that, use Euler's theorem to find a modulus to reduce $2^{23}$ by without changing the result modulo 25. The remaining two exponentiation operations (modulo 20 and 25) are easily within the range of an ordinary calculator, or you can use exponentiation by squaring if working on paper.

Comment: Or you can continue the logic, figuring $2^{23}\pmod {20}$ by noting it is $0\pmod 4$ and $2^3\pmod 5$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes, but that seems to be slightly overkill compared to the size of these numbers. (Or perhaps I'm just assuming that everyone has $2^{20}=1048576$ memorized, so it's just a matter of multiplying 16 and 8 modulo 20 ... :-)

Comment: Yeah, I don't have $2^{20}$ memorized, and I think repeating the logic again in instructive.

Comment: Sorry, occupational injury, I suppose.